RayLib (для Си) не могу подключить русский шрифт
Установил Raylib 5 версия, последняя на 2024. Не могу вывести ничего на русском языке.
Там с raylib идет в комплекте notepad++, компилятор, raylib библиотека. Я вначале в notepad менял различные кодировки.
Потом в примере увидел как загружают свой шрифт TTF. Загрузил свой, подключил, не выводит русский. То квадраты, то вопросительные знаки.
Если у кого есть опыт, как в RayLib вывести на русском, прошу помощи.
Использую Windows 10 64, ЯП Си.

https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/issues/2991?
